# How do I configure GNOME on Fedora 27 to use the U.S. International keyboard layout?

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I switched from Windows to Fedora for quite some time now. I have to write papers using a lot of special characters like `μ`, `ë` and `°`.

Using the compose key is simply too slow, and I'd rather replace the whole input mechanism to what windows uses... (shudder)


<kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> for `μ` 
<kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd> for `°`.
<kbd>"</kbd> followed by <kbd>e</kbd> for `ë`.

I'd prefer it if I don't have to program this all in myself, can this be done?

Environment: Fedora 27, Gnome 3

Comment: Another way of writing this question is _How do I configure GNOME on Fedora 27 to use the U.S. International keyboard layout?_

Comment: Thank you for this. I did not know I was looking for is the U.S. International keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work, seems like Gnome hides some input sources by default, to enable it, run this:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true
```

After that, go to: `Settings > Region and Language` and match your settings to the below screenshot I made.

Thanks a ton to [JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5132/jdebp) for pointing me in the right direction!

[image: Screenshot of settings]

Answer (score 0):

I use compose, but probably use the characters less than you. I have just tried enabling 3rd level shift key. It results in a lot of these characters. You can also enable 5th level (I think 4th level is 3rd level+shirt, and 6th level 5th + shift).

I could not get µ, and I have no idea how to configure it. But I did get êëüçàôéûîâöèùï€ß

Answer (score 0):

On Gnome, you can add the "Character" option to the search settings, then you can quickly press <kbd>Super</kbd> and search for the symbol you need and add it to the clipboard by selecting it in the results.

You can also open the `Characters` program and browse through the available symbols.

Comment: I use these characters very often, copy pasting isn't enough, sadly. Thanks for the suggestion though